# How to create new api for zabbix frontend?

Tags: zabbix

I want to create new API for Zabbix frontend.

I created a file CTestApi.php in the

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\zabbix\include\classes\api\services\CTestApi.php
```

and I created a function

```
public static function TestApi() {
        return self::getApi('testapi');
}
```

I am using postman to test the API. localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php with the param as below

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "testapi.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend"
    },
    "auth": "891692ab3070e64f9d3439278a5bbcb8",
    "id": 1
}
```

The result is

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32602,
        "message": "Invalid params.",
        "data": "Incorrect API \"testapi\"."
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

I don't know why Incorrect API. Please help me how to add new APIs into Zabbix frontend?

I am using PHP 7, MySQL5, Zabbix 4.0

Thank you so much!
BienHV

Answer (score 1):

I was find the solution for this question.

**Step1:** Create API service class
Ex: \include\classes\api\services\CTestApi.php

**Step2:** Register API service factory in CApiServiceFactory.php
Ex: 'testapi' => 'CTestApi'

**Step3:** declare function to return the CApiInstance object for the requested API

**Step4:** Write API function in CTestApi.php
Ex: get, post, … method